# How to change the context menu options when right clicked on iframe tag?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, iframe, contextmenu

I have set up an iframe tag in which i need to change the default context menu and add play pause options in the context menu. How can i add that?

Comment: I tried ng-context menu, but it didn't work. Is der any working code example for right click context menu options in angularjs?

Comment: @Nicolay Hekkens please give me an idea.